# Date interval processing

Tags: sql, date-arithmetic

I wonder if the problem below is feasible by a "solid" SQL (with window functions and without a "self" join of the table) statement not by a stored procedure or function. It looks quite simple, but I failed to find the solution for it, so far.

The problm is:

There is a table T1 with a column of dates.

```
create table T1
(
id bigint not null,
event_date date not null,
PRIMARY KEY (id, event_date)
)

insert into T1 VALUES
('354312','2020-03-01'),
('354312','2020-08-01'),
('354312','2020-12-01'),
('354312','2020-06-30'),
('354312','2020-09-30'),
('354312','2020-08-31'),
('354312','2020-10-31'),
('354312','2020-12-31')
```

Those dates in T1 are starts and ends of a certain processes. They going strictly one after another in T1 (of course if T1 is ordered). I need to form a table T2 with any numeric PK and two columns of dates (start_date and end_date),

```
create table T2
(
id bigint not null primary key,
start_date date not null,
end_date date
)
```

So the date from the first record of T1 will become a start_date in T2 and the date from the second record of T1 will become an end_date in T2. The same goes for the third and forth records, fifth and sixth records and so on untill all records from T1 have been precessed.

I hope that an approach with a recursive query (with recursive...) together with window functions may help.

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
with xxx as (
       select 
        t1.*,
       case
             when mod(t1.rrnn,2) = 1 then t1.effective_date end as eff_from
             ,
       lead((case
             when mod(t1.rrnn,2) = 0 then t1.effective_date end),1) over() as eff_to_pr
       from
       (select 
             *,
             row_number() over(order by effective_date ) as rrnn
             from t1)  
       select id,
              eff_from,
              eff_to_pr
       from xxx where eff_from is not null
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).